# Why doesn't slideDown on error messages work with jQuery validation?

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

So take a look at the code: http://jsfiddle.net/qb34B/

Type an invalid email, hit the Submit button. You will see that the error message fades in.

This is my problem: I want to be able to slideDown the error. But only fadeIn works. How can I get the error message to slideDown?

It needs to work in all browsers that jQuery supports (IE7+, Firefox, Safari, Chrome, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/qb34B/33/) is a working example. In this solution I'm using `float:left` on the form elements and then setting the wrapper option with a div.

```
    <form >
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" style="float:left;"/>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" style="float:left;"/>
    </form>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery('form').validate({
            debug: true,
            rules: {
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                }
            },
            wrapper: 'div',
            messages: {
                email: "Please enter a valid email address."
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                     error.appendTo(element.parent()).hide().slideDown('normal', function() {
                     //callback func
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: @xckpd7 Updated to include code. The main parts are the div wrapper and float:left for the form elements.

Comment: @xckpd7 That's true. I thought one of the requirements was that the error display in the same location as your original fiddle.

Comment: I was just really trying to diagnose what could get it to work... but I appreciate the effort! It seems the wrapper div is the only thing that makes this work. This is going to work much better for me than trying to rewrite the element. Thanks for the answer, works great!

Answer (score 2):

Error is displayed using a `label` element which is an inline element so it cannot be slided(animated changing its height).

If you want sliding behavior then you will have to write code to generate the required markup and apply sliding behavior on it.

Take a look at this demo I have written a custom logic to show sliding effect in case you think of going for custom logic.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qb34B/30/)**

Comment: Take a look at this demo I have written a custom logic to show sliding effect in case you think of going for custom logic.

Comment: This is a little better, but I'm very wary of writing custom markup. Outside of that, the errors in the demo slide up, and in Firefox (10.0, Mac) (going back to me being wary of writing custom markup) you can see that when the error pops up, the form display twitches.

Comment: I understand your concerns but if you have to support multiple browsers you have to have different ways to do it.

Comment: That doesn't help me. Thanks for attempting.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**
I updated the code so that it will successfully slideDown the error and hide. Unfortunately I had to use setInterval which isn't ideal. But it's a workaround if you can't find another way.

http://jsfiddle.net/XrMzL/5/

You could try the following

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    setInterval(function() {
        if($(".valid").prev().hasClass("errorSlideDown")) {
           $(".valid").prev().slideUp();
        }
    },1000);

    jQuery('form').validate({
        debug: true,
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            email: "Please enter a valid email address."
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if (!element.prev().hasClass("errorSlideDown")) {
                var itm = $("<div />").html(error.html()).addClass("errorSlideDown").hide();
                itm.insertBefore(element).slideDown();
            }
        }
    });
    });
```

I used insertBefore to make life easy when checking to see if the dynamic span I created exists already by using the .prev() function.

Comment: unfortunately it appears the slideDown part is only working in FF. IE and Chrome seem to just want it to show.

Comment: I don't think writing a custom element is the best choice: I need those errors later in a way that the validation plugin expects because I also need to fade them out when they are correct, etc etc. And all the above is ignoring the far that this doesn't work in Safari / Chrome / Opera / and I haven't checked IE browsers yet.

Comment: @xckpd7 see my updated answer. It isn't perfect, but it will hide once it is correct. Also tested in IE,FF,Chrome.